# Mostrar imagen según lo que escriba en EditText

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `EditText`

```
ed_image = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edimage);
```

y en mi carpeta `drawable` tres *.png*

```
- image1.png
- image2.png
- image3.png
```

Luego así envío el icono a mi notificación:

```
Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
notification.setLargeIcon(icon1);
```

La pregunta, ¿es posible cambiar `ic_launcher` de `R.drawable.ic_launcher` según lo que escriba en mi `ed_image`?

Es decir, si escribo por ejemplo `image1` el código quede

```
Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pones el adapter al spinner, este es modificado por lo que se activa el listener con la posición 0, para arreglar eso, le indicas que no sea seleccionado, y manualmente se agrega la posición 0 sin notificar el cambio

```
spin.setSelected(false); 
spin.setSelection(0,true);
```

Otra manera que tendrías de hacerlo, es simplemente omitiendo la primera vez que éste es cargado, declarando una variable de clase `boolean primeraEjecucion = true;` y en tu listener ver si es true, en caso de serlo, asignarle false sin hacer nada mas.

```
boolean primeraEjecucion = true;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(primeraEjecucion){
    int imagenes[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    Bitmap iconSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), imagenes[position]);

    // aquí crea una notificación vacía
    creaNotificacion(iconSelected);


    if (position == 0) {
        tv_categoria.setText("diaria");
    } else if (position == 1) {
        tv_categoria.setText("semanal");
    } else if (position == 2) {
        tv_categoria.setText("mensual");
    }
    spin.setSelection(position);
    tv_categoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
     primeraEjecucion = false;
    }
}
```

Y otra manera mas que se me ocurre es que asignes el `setOnItemSelectedListener` en el `setOnTouchListener`

```
spin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(Tab1.this);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Edito:**
En relación a ru edit, si puedes obtener un drawable por un String:

```
String nombreDrawable = "ic_launcher";//nombre de la imagen
int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(nombreDrawable , "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), resID);
notification.setLargeIcon(icon1);
```

Comment: Ninguna solución me ha servido :/ , la primera y segunda no hacen efecto, se sigue creando la notificación vacía y la tercera no envía el icono. Pero igualmente yo busco algo distinto, he editado la pregunta para mostrar lo que intento, no sé si será posible, gracias @Israel !!

Comment: Entiendo que quieres enviar una notificación, con un icono u otro en función a el elemento seleccionado en el spinner. Pero unas dudas, quieres convertir un String a R.drawable.AQUI, donde aquí colocar el string? si es asi, la solución de @Jorgesys me parece mas adecuada. O por otro lado el problema es que al iniciar la Activity recibes una notificación vacía.

Comment: Vamos a olvidar el `Spinner`, edite la pregunta para explicarme mejor :), gracias!

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con lo que pides

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, mil gracias !

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un array con las imágenes y obtener el recurso según la posición del elemento que también inicia con 0 como primer elemento. Al obtener el bitmap puedes agregarlo a un `ImageView`.

De hecho puedes realizar lo mismo con las descripciones que agregas a tu `TextView`:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int imagenes[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};        
        Bitmap iconSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), imagenes[position]);

//*** Agrega aquí un método para enviar el bitmap de la imagen seleccionada a donde desees.
creaNotificacion(iconSelected); 

        String descripcion[] = {"diaria", "semanal", "mensual"};        
        tv_categoria.setText(descripcion[position]);               

                    /*if (position == 0) {
                        tv_categoria.setText("diaria");              
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        tv_categoria.setText("semanal");
                    } else if (position == 2) {
                        tv_categoria.setText("mensual");
                    }*/
                    spin.setSelection(position);
    }
```

Al seleccionar la imagen se envia el bitmap al método  `creaNotificacion()` el cual lo recibe y lo agrega a la notificación:

```
   private void creaNotificacion(Bitmap bmp){

        uniqueID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

// este es el icono que necesito cambiar según lo seleccionado en el `Spinner`

        //Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setLargeIcon(bmp /*icon1*/);

        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle(ed_titulo.getText().toString());
        notification.setContentText(ed_nota.getText().toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, otrointento.dos.Actividades.MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
    }
```

Comment: No mencionas nada acerca de **notificación** en tu pregunta, pero bueno obteniendo la imagen, puedes enviar el bitmap a un método.

Comment: ok perfecto, ahora ve lo que comento :)

Comment: Hay un problema, y es que al utilizar `creaNotificacion(iconSelected);` en `onItemSelected` al abrir la `Activity` crea una notificación vacía

Comment: no habías probado anteriormente tu método para crear la notificación, funciona correctamente?

Comment: Mi método funciona perfecto, pero al añadir `creaNotificacion(iconSelected);` en `onItemSelected` al abrir la `Activity` se ejecuta la notificación y se añade vacía, luego en mi botón yo tengo `crearNotificacion(bmp)` que es el que utilizo y funciona bien

Comment: " en onItemSelected al abrir la Activity se ejecuta la notificación  y se añade vacía"  ??? onItemSelected() se llama al dar click, quieres que al iniciar se llamé la notificación también, simplemente agrega lo mismo en onCreate(), o explicam´pe si no entendi

Comment: He añadido la `Activity` en la pregunta, para que puedas verlo mejor, te he dejado un comentario en el código para que veas donde está el problema de crear una notificación vacía

Comment: Volvi a editar la pregunta !! :D