# Detener TabView

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos `TabView` y el problema es que si por ejemplo tengo un `Toast` en `Tab2` al abrir `Tab1` se ejecuta, cómo puedo hacer para que no "intercambien datos", es decir, si estoy en `Tab1` o `Tab2` que la otra no se active, que este "cerrada"

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

`Activity`

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mis Notas"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Favoritas"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
        (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

**EDITO1:** @Israel

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
    public static RecyclerView recyclerview_notas;
    public static ArrayList<Notas> allNotas;
    public static TextView TxtPersistente, RecyclerVacio;
    static public NotasAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,
                container, false);

            RecyclerVacio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerVacio);
            recyclerview_notas = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_notas);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
            TxtPersistente = new TextView(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
            recyclerview_notas.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerview_notas.setHasFixedSize(true);
            //metodoMuestraRecyclerView();
            return view;
        }

        public void metodoMuestraRecyclerView(){

            mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
            allNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) mDatabase.listNotas();

            if (allNotas.size() > 0) {
                RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAdapter = new NotasAdapter(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext(), allNotas);
                recyclerview_notas.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.filter("favorito");

            } else {
                recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            metodoMuestraRecyclerView();
        }
    }
}
```

`Logcat`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at intento.dos.TabView.Tab1.metodoMuestraRecyclerView(Tab1.java:52)
                                                                   at intento.dos.TabView.Tab1.setUserVisibleHint(Tab1.java:68)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:157)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1266)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2899)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Comment: No se si te entendi bien, prueba a agregar en tu activity `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` donde el 2, es el numero de tabs, no recuerdo si era en base 0 o 1, pero para asegurar coloca 2

Comment: He probado lo que comentas, pero sigo con el mismo problema. Lo que necesito es que sean como dos `Activity` diferente, es decir, que no se "junten" entre si, si agrego un `Toast` en `Tab2` también se ejecuta en `Tab1`, necesito que cada vez que este en un `Tab` los demás no se ejecuten, que cada vez que vaya de uno a otro, cargué de cero ese `Tab`. No sé si será posible, espero haberme explicado ahora bien, gracias @Israel

Comment: Ok, la respuesta que había propuesto es para que se guarden en memoria, prueba esa misma opción colocando 0 en lugar de 2, si eso no es lo que buscas coméntalo. Sobre lo que dices del `Toast`, te refieres a que al lanzarlo en tab1 e ir a tab2 el toast aun es visible ?

Comment: Tampoco ha funcionado con el `0`, a lo que me refiero es que por ejemplo tengo un `Toast` en `Tab2`, inicio la `Activity` que inicia en `Tab1` y se muestra el `Toast` de `Tab2`. Al iniciar la `Activity` se ejecuta el código de ambos `Tab`. Yo quiero que solamente se ejecute el código del `Tab` en el que estoy @Israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propongo sobrescribir el método `setUserVisibleHint` en cada fragment para saber si el `Fragment` es visible, en caso de no serlo, no cargar el contenido de `onCreate`, y en caso de serlo, hay que recargar el contenido de dicho fragment para volver a ejecutar el método onCreate desde el Adapter (Comento las lineas que he agregado):

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
public static RecyclerView recyclerview_notas;
public static ArrayList<Notas> allNotas;
public static TextView TxtPersistente, RecyclerVacio;
static public NotasAdapter mAdapter;

static boolean visible = false;// aqui almacenas el estado del Fragment

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,
            container, false);

        RecyclerVacio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerVacio);
        recyclerview_notas = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_notas);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
        TxtPersistente = new TextView(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
        recyclerview_notas.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerview_notas.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Si el Fragment esta actualmente en la pantalla, ejecuta el metodo
        if(visible)
            metodoMuestraRecyclerView();


        return view;
    }

    public void metodoMuestraRecyclerView(){

        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext());
        allNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) mDatabase.listNotas();

        if (allNotas.size() > 0) {
            RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAdapter = new NotasAdapter(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext(), allNotas);
            recyclerview_notas.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.filter("favorito");

        } else {
            recyclerview_notas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

//este metodo se encarga de comprobar si el fragment esta seleccionado
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    visible = isVisibleToUser; //asignamos a la variable declarada arriba, true o false, segun si esta o no seleccionado el fragment
}
}
```

Ahora para recargar los `Fragment` en el adapter se sobrescribe el metodo `getItemPosition` para que nos permita notificarle cambios:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
}
```

Por ultimo en tu Activity, notificaremos los cambios al hacer click en un tab:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mis Notas"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Favoritas"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
    (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

La solución que te di en los comentarios, `setOffscreenPageLimit` es válida pero con un pequeño detalle, y es que tiene que cargar mínimo 2 Tabs, es decir, puedes evitar recrear el 3, 4... pero siempre el 1 y 2 serán cargados, si cambias al 2, el 1 sera destruido para cargar el 3.

Comment: Hola, @Israel ! gracias por tu respuesta, me parece muy buena, pero estoy teniendo un problema, he añadido el `logcat` y como utilizo el código en la pregunta, se me cierra al entrar el `Tab1`, lo que necesito es que cargue ese método cuando inicia, porque en `Tab2` tengo el mismo `RecyclerView` pero con otro filtro. Pero si cargo el método como me comentas se cierra, si lo utilizo fuera del `setUserVisibleHint` funciona bien, pero es lo que necesito que se recargue cuando cambias de `Tab`

Comment: He editado la respuesta por completo con lo que creo una solución mas elegante a la hora de recargar los fragment, cualquier problema házmelo saber.

Comment: Ahora sí! Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, mil gracias!! Una duda, con los cambios en `PagerAdapter` que sino me equivoco lo que realiza es volver a cargar el `Fragment`, la transición es muy fea, pega como un salto al cambiar de `Tab`  pero imagino que no hay solución para eso, o si? Gracias !!

Comment: Realmente no se si habra una buena manera, ya que para eso mismo android mantiene en memoria los Tabs, podrías probar en un nuevo thread o asyntask, me refiero a algo como: `if(visible)
        {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            metodoMuestraRecyclerView();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();
        }`

Comment: Lo que me comentas mejora un poco la fluidez, pero sigue sin ser del todo fluido, si se te ocurre algo me avisas :), voy a marcar como solucionado, por la magnifica respuesta, mil gracias!! @Israel por cierto, si puedes pasate por esta otra pregunta que hice: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81032/mostrar-imagen-según-la-posición-en-spinner